# In first load of action, how do I pass instance variables to js.erb?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb, ruby-on-rails-5, ujs

I have a `ProfilesController` that has the following:

```
if @profile.ratings
  @rating = @profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user)
end
```

When the page is just loaded, before it even sends a request back to the controller, for it to `respond_to`, I would like to access that `@rating` instance variable in my `app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.erb` file like so:

```
console.log('<%= @rating %>');
```

It just returns as `nil` now.

How do I get access to that `@rating` instance variable in that `profile.js.erb` on the first load?

**Edit 1**

For some clarity and more context, this is what is happening.

I have some JS powered `UISliders` that look like this:

[image]

The HTML that generates this is (along with more like it) - `Profile#Show.html.erb`:

```
        <td>
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm slider-step-value" id="slider-step-value-speed-<%= @profile.slug %>">5</button>
              Speed
            </p>
            <div id="slider-speed" class="slider"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-r-sm slider-step-value" id="slider-step-value-tackling-<%= @profile.slug %>">3</button>
              Tackling
            </p>
            <div id="slider-tackling" class="slider"></div>
        </td>
```

This is the JS - `app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.erb` - that corresponds to that HTML:

```
  var sliders = $('.slider');
  var buttons = $('.slider-step-value');

  for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
    var button = $(sliders[i]).prev('p').find('button')[0];
    var _slider_type = sliders[i].id.split('-')[1];
    console.log(_slider_type);
    console.log('<%= @rating %>');
    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
      start: 5,
      step: 1,
      behaviour: 'tap',
      connect: [true, false],
      range: {
        'min':  1,
        'max':  10
      }
    });

    attachEvent(sliders[i], button);
  }

  function attachEvent(slider,button){
    slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
      button.innerText = parseInt(values[handle]);
      var _profile_id = button.id.split('-').slice(4).join('-');
      var _rating_type = button.id.split('-')[3]
      var url = "/profiles/" + _profile_id + "/" + _rating_type + "_rating/?" + _rating_type + "=" + button.innerText

      $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: url,
        success: function(){
          // console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was successfully updated.");
        },
        error: function(){
          // console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was NOT successfully updated.");
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

This is my `ProfilesController#Show` action:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :invite_user, :speed_rating, :tackling_rating, :dribbling_rating, :passing_rating]
  authorize_resource except: [:dashboard, :speed_rating, :dribbling_rating, :tackling_rating, :passing_rating]
  skip_authorization_check only: [:dashboard, :speed_rating, :dribbling_rating, :tackling_rating, :passing_rating]

def show
    if @profile.ratings
      @rating = @profile.ratings.find_by(user: current_user)
    end
end
end
```

So the issue is that on the first load, what happens is the HTML loads the default values that are hardcoded in the HTML (I will eventually change this to the normal db-values, that's straightforward). Then after the JS is loaded, this `noUiSlider` script updates both the value of the `button` tag (aka the colorful box) and the position of the slider.

The way it does that is at this line:

```
noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
          start: 5,
```

So rather than just defaulting to `5`, I want it to pull `@rating` from my `Profiles#Show` controller, so something like `start: <%= @rating %>`. That would automagically update both the Slider & `button` (aka colorful box) like I want.

The issue is on the first page load, `@rating` is nil/empty. So that's what I am struggling with.

Perhaps I need to send a `get` request, but I am unsure about how to approach this.

**Edit 2**

For the record, the AJAX call works and updates the DB like I expect. That happens when I move the slider, AFTER it has initially loaded though. So the issue is on the first page load only, I need the slider & `button` to be updated if there is a value in `@rating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Basically the best way for me to approach this was to add a `data` attribute to each of the `button` tags that pull from the db on initial load.

So while my old `button` tag looked like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm slider-step-value" id="slider-step-value-speed-<%= @profile.slug %>">5</button>
```

My new `button` tag looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm slider-step-value" id="slider-step-value-speed-<%= @profile.slug %>" data-speed-value="<%= speed_rating %>"><%= speed_rating %></button>
```

Where `speed_rating` is a helper method defined in my `profiles_helper.rb` that looks like this:

```
  def speed_rating
    if @rating.speed
      @rating.speed
    else
      "5"
    end
  end
```

Then, in my JS, all I did was select that `data` attribute for each button like this:

```
var button = $(sliders[i]).prev('p').find('button')[0];
var _slider_type = sliders[i].id.split('-')[1];
var _original_value = $('button#' + button.id).data(_slider_type + "-value");
```

The only new line was this:

`var _original_value = $('button#' + button.id).data(_slider_type + "-value");`

Then I just add that to my `noUiSlider.create` call, so now it looks like this:

```
noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
  start: _original_value,
```

As opposed to it originally looked like this:

```
noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
   start: 5,
```

And voila....works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me, because you've said you're trying to render @rating, but then you wrote code that renders '<%= @profile.ratings %>'. Also, the if statement you shared suggests that sometimes that field is nil. I'll see what I can do but I think you need to post more information.

I'm imagining you have a page like this:

```
<%# profile.html.erb %>
<div id="profiles">
  ...
  <button data-remote="true" >Load ratings</button>
</div>
```

and then when you click this button, it sends a request to your controller with :js format, which loads your profile.js.erb.

There **must** be a controller action displaying any text. If you're looking at an HTML page from rails, there is some controller action somewhere. You need to add the @rating instance variable to that controller action, and render it in the corresponding view.

Could you post:

1. What route (url) you're accessing
2. What controller that route is rendered by
3. What view (if any) that route is rendered by

Comment: You are correct re: the `@profile.ratings`. That was a typo. I was debugging and I left it in there. My bad. In terms of the rest of the question, you are not correct. What's happening is I have a jquery powered `noUiSlider` that allows the user to modify the rating. It defaults to `5`, if there is nothing in the db, and then once they move the slider it updates the db with the correct rating for that attribute. So there is no 'click this button, which sends a request to your controller'. All of that is happening within the js `$.ajax` function which is why I am asking this.

Comment: I updated the question with more specifics about what I am doing and why this doesn't work the way you specified/reasonably expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access that variable from `profiles.js.erb`, put its calculation into `profiles` action of the corresponding controller. Currently, it's calculated in another action and, naturally, not available in `profiles`.

Comment: I need to access that variable from `profiles.js.erb`, which manipulates the `profiles/show.html.erb`. Right now, it is calculated within the `ProfilesController#Show` action like I specified in the question.

Comment: @marcamillion: I could swear I've seen it in profiles action. Oh well, the answer is still the same. If you need it in `profiles.js.erb` view, set it in `profiles` action.

Comment: Ahhh...ok. Or I could just rename that `profiles.js.erb` to `show.js.erb`, right?

Comment: Ok....I will have to take a look at this and rejig it. Maybe I need to pull out some of this logic that's in my `profile.js` and put it inside a new `show.js.erb` and then pull the variable from there. That sounds like it should work, right?

Comment: @marcamillion: yep, some rearrangement of code could improve the situation.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will play around with it and see how it goes.

Comment: So that didn't go as planned. I guess the issue is that the `show.js.erb` isn't executed on page load, right? It is only executed when triggered explicitly? I have moved all the JS from my `profile.js.erb` to `views/profiles/show.js.erb` and now it doesn't initialize the sliders at all, whereas it did before. I am at a loss for how to initialize it. Should I call `show.js.erb` from within `profile.js`? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: @marcamillion Or you could just follow my initial recommendation

Comment: I am going to try that and see what happens. The issue is that breaks Rails conventions. In the sense that all of my JS is in my `app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.erb`, so creating a `ProfilesController#Profile` action to feed an instance variable to my `app/views/profiles/show.html.erb` feels weird. Edit: So I just tried it and it doesn't work. `@rating` is still blank in my `console.log(' <%= @rating %>');`

Comment: Ah, so profiles.js.erb is not a view for a JS action? That's new. This problem needs some interactive debugging, I think.

Comment: Yeh....my bad. It's not a view for a JS action. It really began as `app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js`, but then I just added `.erb` in an attempt to access that `@rating` variable, but that doesn't work in this instance. I updated the question to reflect this. What do you suggest, re: interactive debugging?

Comment: @marcamillion: I think you'll get it sorted out much quicker if you go to sites like codementor or airpair (or maybe there are others) and make someone look at your entire code and maybe see it in action (logs and whatnot). It's not free, though.

Comment: Ugghh...not really the answer I was looking for :(